# Word VBA Macro to Clean Empty Paragraphs and Add space after & before

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this little macro whose purpose is to remove all the empty paragraphs (^p) and then select all paragraphs and add space after and before (6 points each).

This is the code so far

```
Sub format()

ActiveDocument.Range.Select

' Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
.text = "^p^p"
.Replacement.text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchByte = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchFuzzy = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


iParCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
For J = 1 To iParCount
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).SpaceAfter = 6
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).SpaceBefore = 6
Next J
End Sub
```

However when I run it, everything becomes a single paragraph. Supose I have like (^p are empty paragraphs)

```
paragraph 1 
^p
paragraph 2 
^p
paragraph 3
```

I always get

```
paragraph 1 paragraph 2 paragraph 3
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you "before" paragraph example is incorrect. have another look at your paragraphs. then think about what you are replacing with what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this with a loop and start from the end of the document so that deleted paragraphs are eliminated from the count.

```
Sub FormatParagraphs()

    Dim Para As Paragraph
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set Para = .Paragraphs(i)
            With Para
                If .Range.End - .Range.Start = 1 Then
                    .Range.Delete
                Else
                    .SpaceBefore = 6
                    .SpaceAfter = 6
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```